# Spatie/laravel-permission. hasRole() on null

Tags: php, laravel, permissions

Added spatie/laravel-permission, everything works by middleware in routes/api.php

```
Route::get('roles', [RoleController::class, 'rolesIndex'])->middleware('role:Admin');
```

I wanted to make a role check for api and added a function:

```
   function check($roleName) {
     $user = Auth::user();
     if (!$user->hasRole($roleName)) {
       abort(403);
     }
     return response('', 202);
   }
```

Added to the router - addressing the route:

```
Route::get('check/{roleName}', [RoleController::class, 'check']);
```

But when contacting me it gives: **Call to a member function hasRole() on null**

Comment: use optional, because Auth can return null.`optional(Auth::user())->hasRole()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the authenticated `user` of your `API`, you'll need to reference the `api` guard:

```
$user = auth('api')->user();
if (!$user->hasRole($roleName) {
    // ...
}
```

Or simpler still:

```
if (!auth('api')->user()->hasRole($roleName)) {
    // ...
}
```